# Get substring between '-' and next numeric character in Pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho

How can I get this in Pentaho?

I want to cut a substring from a string of pattern like

```
M- L'Eau Par Kenzo 1.7 Spy Edt
```

I want the text after `-` and before the first numeric character i.e `1.7`.

Comment: show the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I would use regexes. In your case, the regex `-([^0-9]+)` matches what you want.

It finds a `-`, then captures everything non-numeric after it, stopping if there is a number.

Information on regexes in Pentaho can be found [here](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Regex+Evaluation).

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply . Can you please share the exact code which search - and numeric character in string and cut the character between - and numeric charcacter. I am new to java script.

Answer (score -1):

You can use, as suggested by @Laurel, a REGEX Eval step.

I've built a quick demo and left the code here together with this screenshot.
[image: demo]

## TRANSFORMATION CODE - XML source

> **How to use:** Paste to a empty text file and save as 'demo.ktr'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transformation>
  <info>
    <name>REGEX_for_dash_separated_string</name>
    <description/>
    <extended_description/>
    <trans_version/>
    <trans_type>Normal</trans_type>
    <directory>&#x2f;</directory>
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
    <log>
<trans-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<size_limit_lines/>
<interval/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STATUS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STATUS</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name><subject/></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name><subject/></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>STARTDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STARTDATE</name></field><field><id>ENDDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ENDDATE</name></field><field><id>LOGDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGDATE</name></field><field><id>DEPDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>DEPDATE</name></field><field><id>REPLAYDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPLAYDATE</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field><field><id>EXECUTING_SERVER</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>EXECUTING_SERVER</name></field><field><id>EXECUTING_USER</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>EXECUTING_USER</name></field><field><id>CLIENT</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>CLIENT</name></field></trans-log-table>
<perf-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<interval/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>SEQ_NR</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>SEQ_NR</name></field><field><id>LOGDATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGDATE</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STEPNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEPNAME</name></field><field><id>STEP_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEP_COPY</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>INPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name></field><field><id>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OUTPUT_BUFFER_ROWS</name></field></perf-log-table>
<channel-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOGGING_OBJECT_TYPE</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_NAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_NAME</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_COPY</name></field><field><id>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY</name></field><field><id>FILENAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>FILENAME</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_ID</name></field><field><id>OBJECT_REVISION</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>OBJECT_REVISION</name></field><field><id>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>PARENT_CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ROOT_CHANNEL_ID</name></field></channel-log-table>
<step-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>TRANSNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>TRANSNAME</name></field><field><id>STEPNAME</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEPNAME</name></field><field><id>STEP_COPY</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>STEP_COPY</name></field><field><id>LINES_READ</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_READ</name></field><field><id>LINES_WRITTEN</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_WRITTEN</name></field><field><id>LINES_UPDATED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_UPDATED</name></field><field><id>LINES_INPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_INPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_OUTPUT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_OUTPUT</name></field><field><id>LINES_REJECTED</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LINES_REJECTED</name></field><field><id>ERRORS</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ERRORS</name></field><field><id>LOG_FIELD</id><enabled>N</enabled><name>LOG_FIELD</name></field></step-log-table>
<metrics-log-table><connection/>
<schema/>
<table/>
<timeout_days/>
<field><id>ID_BATCH</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>ID_BATCH</name></field><field><id>CHANNEL_ID</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>CHANNEL_ID</name></field><field><id>LOG_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>LOG_DATE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_DATE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_DATE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_CODE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_CODE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_DESCRIPTION</name></field><field><id>METRICS_SUBJECT</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_SUBJECT</name></field><field><id>METRICS_TYPE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_TYPE</name></field><field><id>METRICS_VALUE</id><enabled>Y</enabled><name>METRICS_VALUE</name></field></metrics-log-table>
    </log>
    <maxdate>
      <connection/>
      <table/>
      <field/>
      <offset>0.0</offset>
      <maxdiff>0.0</maxdiff>
    </maxdate>
    <size_rowset>10000</size_rowset>
    <sleep_time_empty>50</sleep_time_empty>
    <sleep_time_full>50</sleep_time_full>
    <unique_connections>N</unique_connections>
    <feedback_shown>Y</feedback_shown>
    <feedback_size>50000</feedback_size>
    <using_thread_priorities>Y</using_thread_priorities>
    <shared_objects_file/>
    <capture_step_performance>N</capture_step_performance>
    <step_performance_capturing_delay>1000</step_performance_capturing_delay>
    <step_performance_capturing_size_limit>100</step_performance_capturing_size_limit>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
    <partitionschemas>
    </partitionschemas>
    <slaveservers>
    </slaveservers>
    <clusterschemas>
    </clusterschemas>
  <created_user>-</created_user>
  <created_date>2016&#x2f;08&#x2f;08 12&#x3a;00&#x3a;56.365</created_date>
  <modified_user>-</modified_user>
  <modified_date>2016&#x2f;08&#x2f;08 12&#x3a;00&#x3a;56.365</modified_date>
    <key_for_session_key/>
    <is_key_private>N</is_key_private>
  </info>
  <notepads>
  </notepads>
  <order>
  <hop> <from>Data Grid</from><to>Regex Evaluation</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  <hop> <from>Regex Evaluation</from><to>Dummy &#x28;do nothing&#x29;</to><enabled>Y</enabled> </hop>
  </order>
  <step>
    <name>Data Grid</name>
    <type>DataGrid</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>test_string</name>
        <type/>
        <format/>
        <currency/>
        <decimal/>
        <group/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <set_empty_string>N</set_empty_string>
      </field>
    </fields>
    <data>
      <line> <item>M- L&#x27;Eau Par Kenzo 1.7 Spy Edt</item> </line>
      <line> <item>abc123 56&#x25; &#x23; - testTESTtest &#x25; a &#x5e;1 h &#x3d;&#x29;</item> </line>
      <line> <item/> </line>
    </data>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>128</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Regex Evaluation</name>
    <type>RegexEval</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
    <script><![CDATA[(.*)[\-](.*)]]></script>    <matcher>test_string</matcher>
    <resultfieldname>REGEX_evaluation</resultfieldname>
    <usevar>N</usevar>
    <allowcapturegroups>Y</allowcapturegroups>
    <replacefields>Y</replacefields>
    <canoneq>N</canoneq>
    <caseinsensitive>N</caseinsensitive>
    <comment>N</comment>
    <dotall>N</dotall>
    <multiline>N</multiline>
    <unicode>N</unicode>
    <unix>N</unix>
    <fields>
      <field>
        <name>first_block_before_the_dash</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <group/>
        <decimal/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <nullif/>
        <ifnull/>
        <trimtype>none</trimtype>
      </field>
      <field>
        <name>last_block_after_the_dash</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <format/>
        <group/>
        <decimal/>
        <length>-1</length>
        <precision>-1</precision>
        <nullif/>
        <ifnull/>
        <trimtype>none</trimtype>
      </field>
    </fields>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>256</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step>
    <name>Dummy &#x28;do nothing&#x29;</name>
    <type>Dummy</type>
    <description/>
    <distribute>Y</distribute>
    <custom_distribution/>
    <copies>1</copies>
         <partitioning>
           <method>none</method>
           <schema_name/>
           </partitioning>
     <cluster_schema/>
 <remotesteps>   <input>   </input>   <output>   </output> </remotesteps>    <GUI>
      <xloc>400</xloc>
      <yloc>32</yloc>
      <draw>Y</draw>
      </GUI>
    </step>

  <step_error_handling>
  </step_error_handling>
   <slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
</slave-step-copy-partition-distribution>
   <slave_transformation>N</slave_transformation>

</transformation>
```